# Katana OWIN Assembly Dependency Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

So, I've been following Scott Allen's tutorial on OWIN and Katana and decided to try it out starting from an empty Web Api project.

I've installed the Nuget Packages in the order as he did :

```
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
Microsoft.Aspnet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

However, when I run it from IIS, I keep on getting this error :

[image: Error]

If I downgrade the Owin's version via Nuget to 2.0.2.0, I get a similar error with reference to Newtonsoft.Json to 6.0.0.0 and if I downgrade that, it downgrade other packges and raises another error for Newtonsoft.Json to 4.5.0.0

I've tried reinstalling packages, ensuring that the web.config file has the right convention etc. but to no avail. I've also tried starting from a web console app and if it runs using the console, there is no issue. Only in IIS.

Any help anyone?

Comment: OwinSelfHost with HttpListener - Isnt that supposed to be hosted via a Console App??

Comment: Yeap it is. I was just following throught he tutorial steps. Nevertheless, even if I started off with the console app, and then later shifted it to IIS, the issue remains the same.

Comment: Ok - Regarding the Error - Check the nuget Packages.config and the csproj file - thats where you can see the PublicKeyToken thing... try removing specific keyToken and see if that resolves.

Comment: Yep tried that earlier too haha it didn't work.